# CE button code not working in a basic C# calculator

Tags: c#, visual-studio

for my final task in my school I choose to create a calculator in C# and ASP.NET. Everything was going well until I came to the CE button(deletes the last character that you inputed). The problem is that the code I have written should work (at least I think it should because I did it like a solution on this site says I should) but it doesn't.

this is the code :

```
         try
        {
            string s = TBracun.Text;
            s.Remove(s.Length - 1);
            TBracun.Text = s;

        }
        catch
        {
            TBracun.Text = "Ni mogoče!";
        }
```

Comment: "The problem is that the code I have written should work[..] but it doesn't." - This is not very helpful. What about it doesn't work? Does it not compile? Does it throw an exception at runtime? Does it remove the wrong character? Tell us what exactly went wrong and it makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: It compiles and there are no errors. It's just that the button does not work if I press it to delete the last character. When I press the button the site refreshes but it doesn't delete the last character, but it does work if there are no characters in the textbox because it returns the "Ni mogoče!" sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
TBracun.Text = s.Remove(s.Length - 1);
```

MSDN explains how the Remove() command works here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8d7z2kk%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: The key piece here is that strings are immutable, `Remove` must return a new string as it cannot modify the existing one.

Comment: I tried it but it still doesnt work. When I press the button the site refreshes but it still doesn't delete the last character.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Does that mean that I should create a new string which saves the string that the Remove() function returns?

Comment: @DomenNovak That's more or less what this answer does, it just puts it on the UI directly. Sounds like you have a different issue as well as the one Phil found.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET and Phil N DeBlanc, thank you for your help, I found the solution.